# Create Skew Responsive Background

Tags: html, css, background

I am looking to make this kind of background. And I have to admit that I am in troubles ... Can't find the good way to do it.

I tried with `transform : skewY(-6deg)` for example. But `-6deg` my entire page.

Can someone help me to find the good way to do it ?

[image: Here is the picture of the design example]

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background and gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:250px;
  padding:50px 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,#0060ff 50%)top/100% 50px,
    linear-gradient(#0060ff,#0060ff) center/100% calc(100% - 100px),
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49%,#0060ff 50%)bottom/100% 50px,
    
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#00dbf8 50%)top/100% 50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

You can make it more flexible with CSS variable in order to easily control the skewing:

```css
.box {
  height:150px;
  padding:var(--p,50px) 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,#0060ff 50%)top/100% var(--p,50px),
    linear-gradient(#0060ff,#0060ff) center/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--p,50px)),
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49%,#0060ff 50%)bottom/100% var(--p,50px),
    
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#00dbf8 50%)top/100% var(--p,50px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="box" style="--p:100px;">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="box" style="--p:40px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a good starting point:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="skewed">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content of the skewed container</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skewed {
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-6deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-6deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-6deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-6deg);
  transform: skewX(-6deg);
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.content {
  -webkit-transform: skewX(6deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(6deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(6deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(6deg);
  transform: skewX(6deg);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

[Code](https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/oJxgoj)